# How to validate start and end time?

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have below TS code.

```
 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
 }   
  
 ngOnInit(): void { 
     this.formBuilder.group({
      startTime: ['', Validators.required],
      endTime: ['', Validators.required],
    })
}
```

& HTML code is like below

```
  <input type="number" formControlName="startTime"  placeholder="0:00" value="0:00" step="0.01" />
  <input type="number" formControlName="endTime"  placeholder="0:00" value="0:00" step="0.01" />
```

I have below issues

1. Input type `number` goes above 0.6 which is correct, but not for
   the hour/minutes.
2. I have hour: minute format in `06:10` so it
   should be validated may be `Validator.pattern` & End should be
   greater than start (May be need to use custom validators)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you used the wrong formControlName in your input elements. Defined as `startTime` but you used `start` in your HTML.

Check this code and see if it does what you want or not. I only handled `startTime` by listening to its changes. You can write a custom validator for it. I usually don't let the user to do the wrong thing rather than showing an error.

Component's ngOnInit as you wrote your code there:

```
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      startTime: ['', Validators.required],
      endTime: ['', Validators.required],
    });

    this.formGroup.controls['startTime'].valueChanges.subscribe(
      (value: number) => {
        let changedValue = value;
        if (value % 1 > 0.59) {
          changedValue = Math.floor(value) + 1;
          if (changedValue > 24) {
            changedValue = 0.00;
          }
          this.formGroup?.controls['startTime'].setValue(changedValue.toFixed(2), {emitEvent: false});
        }
      }
    );
```

HTML Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <div>
      <input type="number"
             formControlName="startTime"
             placeholder="0:00"
             value="0:00"
             step="0.01"
             min="0.00"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="number"
             formControlName="endTime"
             placeholder="0:00"
             value="0:00"
             step="0.01"
             min="0.00"/>
    </div>
  </form>
```

BTW I think there are better approaches for handling time inputs. It's not very easy to use for the user I think.

Hope it's helpful.
G00D LUCK.